# Delay Javascript or div until page load

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, delay, pageload

I've been looking around for a solution, trying a few suggestion but none seem to work for the script I've got or don't understand the solutions properly, so hoping there is someone out there that can help.

In the head tag I've got the javascript script below. It slides the 8th div on the page up from the bottom into the page. However, when you visit the page you get a quick glance of the contents of this div (a block of text) in its end position, before it slides into the page. How do I get rid of this quick preview and get the text block div to slide in when the main image is loaded?

Link to site: http://www.estilosalon.com.au/estilo-salon-philosophy2.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
i=-700;
var c;
function f(){
    c=setInterval(function(){inv()},5)
}
function inv()
{
    if(i!=0)
    {
        i+=5;
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[8].style.bottom=i+"px";
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(c);
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you control over the markup? It would probably be better to grab the div by an `id` rather by its count in the page.

Comment: you could make it invisible before javascript touches it. Also consider moving the script after the element so that you don't have to use your wait loop.

Comment: Maybe simple set `bottom: -700px;` for the div before the animation... There's already an inline `style` attribute, that's a good place.

Comment: Just tried the -700px; suggestion of you Teemu, and that seems to work. I've uploaded your change on http://www.estilosalon.com.au/estilo-salon-philosophy3.html. Maybe I'll opt for this option seeing that there is less code involved than darshanags suggestion. Though, curious if the class="no-js" is a good thing to include as a standard to any webpage?

Comment: Thanks Jacob for your suggestion, that crossed my mind as well though I wouldn't know how to change it in the Javascript to reflect this. Looks like I've got some great solutions to my question already, but thanks anyway. And Jan, I've tried putting the script at the end of the code but that didn't seem to do the trick. No idea how to do the hide before Javascript touches it thing, also not sure about the wait loop thingy, got this javascript from somewhere else, I didn't write it myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

Add a class to your `<html>` tag as a fallback when there is no js:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="no-js">
```

Replace the `no-js` class with `js` class by placing this code before `i=-700;` line

```
var html = document.documentElement;
html.className=html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'') + 'js';
```

Add this to your style sheet

```
html.js #text_box_philosophy{
    bottom: -700px;
}
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks for responding so quickly. I've tried your instructions and it seems to have worked! Just to check with you if I did the right thing; I changed my '<html>' to <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="no-js">' and placed the 'var html' code before 'i=-700;' and added the last bit to the style sheet. I'm just not sure what you mean by 'in your js, replace this no-js class with js class', not sure how to read this. Uploaded the changes so you can see on http://www.estilosalon.com.au/estilo-salon-philosophy2.html. Thanks again!

Comment: @zalia sorry about my grammar, I was in a hurry when I wrote down the steps. I've corrected this in my answer above. I simply meant that you need to replace the `no-js` class with `js` using the code I specified. I see that you have added another `<script>` tag to add my code, while this works it is not necessary - you could have just added the two lines to the top of the `<script>` tag that you already had. I see an error in my console, you may want to check it out. Also, if this answers your question, it's best that you mark it as answered.

Comment: I've added the two lines of script within the tags I already had. Still bit confused over whether I need to add `no-js` or `js` or nothing at all to the html tag. I've removed it and it seems to work, but perhaps I should add `no-js` or `js`?! If you could let me know that would be great. Thanks so much for helping me out, after a few hours trying it does get frustrating and great to know there are guys like you around to assist. I will mark it answered now, just wanted to try everyone's suggestions :-)

Comment: `no-js` is there to help you style anything in case there is no javascript in the end user's browser - it acts like a helper class. The code will work without the `no-js` class in the `<html>` tag but there is no harm in keeping it there. The code i provided is an excerpt from modernizr and you can check it out if you are interested: http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/annotatedsource.html#section-103

Comment: Cheers for that. I've bookmarked that page so I can refer back to it some time. Can't tell you how grateful I am this issue is sorted now :-) Ta!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a function to the body's load event `<body onload="f()">` and set div[8] to `display: none` in your css and then set it to `document.getElementsByTagName("div")[8].style.display = "block"` in `f()`.

However, I would strongly consider using jQuery and the [`$().animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to animate the div, assigning the div an id (if you add more `div` elements before it, your code will break), and using jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function to fire the initial code rather than using `<body onload="">`. Taking these steps will help your code perform uniformly across multiple browsers.

Comment: I see your point that jQuery would be the preferred method, I'll will look into it but at this stage I'll go with the other fixes suggested. I tried to apply what you said, I think I'm getting the bit where to insert "document.getElements...." wrong, see here how I understood it: http://www.estilosalon.com.au/estilo-salon-philosophy4.html. Thanks for your time any way Jacob.